# Reading an XML using System.XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently trying to read a given XML file that holds certain nodes with a specific name and children. This is done inside a function in which the user selects a specific value for RATED_CURRENT. if the values match the RATED_CURRENT value then read the child nodes if not send error codes.

What I am having trouble with is that Currently if the above code I am not getting the correct Inner Text and Name of some nodes. For example, If an at the node named "RATED_CURRENT" when I check for its inner value I should get the corresponding value that belongs to the node. This should be the same for other nodes in the XML file.
For it is an example....
User Inputed: Current 1240;
Go through all of the Nodes labeled as "RATED CURRENT"
if the inner node text matches what the user selected...
"Read the Child nodes for the node.

This is the specific XML file in question.

```
<ROOT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>48<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>7788<SAMPLE_COUNT>1</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>7255<SAMPLE_COUNT>1</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>7442<SAMPLE_COUNT>1</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>7280<SAMPLE_COUNT>1</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>6987<SAMPLE_COUNT>1</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>7649<SAMPLE_COUNT>1</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>76<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>2000<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>1898<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>1946<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>1938<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>1861<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>1991<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>110<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>13610<SAMPLE_COUNT>12</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>12976<SAMPLE_COUNT>12</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>13248<SAMPLE_COUNT>12</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>11873<SAMPLE_COUNT>12</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>11218<SAMPLE_COUNT>12</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>11810<SAMPLE_COUNT>12</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>140<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>14507<SAMPLE_COUNT>3</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>13651<SAMPLE_COUNT>3</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>13985<SAMPLE_COUNT>3</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>12254<SAMPLE_COUNT>3</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>11439<SAMPLE_COUNT>3</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>12239<SAMPLE_COUNT>3</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>150<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>4251<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>4116<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>4252<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>2376<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>2292<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>2552<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>210<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>14847<SAMPLE_COUNT>37</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>14530<SAMPLE_COUNT>37</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>14343<SAMPLE_COUNT>37</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>13887<SAMPLE_COUNT>37</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>13000<SAMPLE_COUNT>37</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14031<SAMPLE_COUNT>37</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>270<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>14028<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>14197<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>13941<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>12084<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>11614<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>11836<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>340<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>14107<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>14013<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>14013<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>10017<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>9522<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>10073<SAMPLE_COUNT>19</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>400<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>16255<SAMPLE_COUNT>15</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>16057<SAMPLE_COUNT>15</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>16058<SAMPLE_COUNT>15</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14274<SAMPLE_COUNT>15</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14188<SAMPLE_COUNT>15</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14250<SAMPLE_COUNT>15</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>520<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>16884<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>16640<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>16628<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>16509<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>16324<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>16434<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>650<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>17737<SAMPLE_COUNT>158</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17578<SAMPLE_COUNT>158</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>17560<SAMPLE_COUNT>159</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>13387<SAMPLE_COUNT>157</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>13142<SAMPLE_COUNT>157</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>13380<SAMPLE_COUNT>157</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>770<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>17697<SAMPLE_COUNT>30</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17545<SAMPLE_COUNT>30</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>17314<SAMPLE_COUNT>30</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>15103<SAMPLE_COUNT>30</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>15085<SAMPLE_COUNT>31</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>15147<SAMPLE_COUNT>31</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>960<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>17773<SAMPLE_COUNT>35</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17483<SAMPLE_COUNT>35</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>17564<SAMPLE_COUNT>35</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>13687<SAMPLE_COUNT>39</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>12953<SAMPLE_COUNT>39</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14006<SAMPLE_COUNT>39</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>1000<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>8648<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>8704<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>8632<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>8726<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>8603<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>8658<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>1240<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18592<SAMPLE_COUNT>40</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18406<SAMPLE_COUNT>39</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18278<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>13423<SAMPLE_COUNT>44</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>13442<SAMPLE_COUNT>44</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>13818<SAMPLE_COUNT>44</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>1560<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18324<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18060<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18064<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14810<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14748<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14880<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>1800<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>17812<SAMPLE_COUNT>20</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18000<SAMPLE_COUNT>20</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>17760<SAMPLE_COUNT>20</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>8999<SAMPLE_COUNT>20</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>8939<SAMPLE_COUNT>20</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>9082<SAMPLE_COUNT>20</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>2400<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18169<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17984<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18099<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14487<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14281<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14539<SAMPLE_COUNT>41</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>3020<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18109<SAMPLE_COUNT>161</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17972<SAMPLE_COUNT>161</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18218<SAMPLE_COUNT>161</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>10880<SAMPLE_COUNT>161</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>10808<SAMPLE_COUNT>161</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>10940<SAMPLE_COUNT>161</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>3610<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18180<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18201<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18287<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14332<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14352<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14669<SAMPLE_COUNT>18</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>4140<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>13446<SAMPLE_COUNT>50</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>13276<SAMPLE_COUNT>50</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>13523<SAMPLE_COUNT>50</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>8559<SAMPLE_COUNT>50</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>8546<SAMPLE_COUNT>50</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>8591<SAMPLE_COUNT>50</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>4770<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18244<SAMPLE_COUNT>28</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18035<SAMPLE_COUNT>28</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18248<SAMPLE_COUNT>28</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14549<SAMPLE_COUNT>28</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14654<SAMPLE_COUNT>28</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14792<SAMPLE_COUNT>28</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>5150<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>20204<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>19075<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18908<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>15224<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>15193<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>15598<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>5340<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>17684<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17164<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>17620<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>10376<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>10368<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>10384<SAMPLE_COUNT>4</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>5900<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18530<SAMPLE_COUNT>21</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18285<SAMPLE_COUNT>21</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18764<SAMPLE_COUNT>22</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>11232<SAMPLE_COUNT>23</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>11377<SAMPLE_COUNT>23</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>11356<SAMPLE_COUNT>23</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>6550<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18260<SAMPLE_COUNT>97</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17720<SAMPLE_COUNT>96</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18138<SAMPLE_COUNT>97</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14168<SAMPLE_COUNT>97</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14069<SAMPLE_COUNT>97</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14233<SAMPLE_COUNT>97</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>7200<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>21886<SAMPLE_COUNT>5</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>21102<SAMPLE_COUNT>5</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>21829<SAMPLE_COUNT>5</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14794<SAMPLE_COUNT>5</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14456<SAMPLE_COUNT>5</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14569<SAMPLE_COUNT>5</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>8400<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18859<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>18552<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18254<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>10124<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>10116<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>10142<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>9600<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>18906<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>17818<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>18488<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>14392<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>14402<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14361<SAMPLE_COUNT>2</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
  <RATED_CURRENT>10800<I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR>19218<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR>19312<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR>19066<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_LINE_EST_C_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR>15085<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_A_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR>15020<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_B_SCALAR><I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR>14888<SAMPLE_COUNT>7</SAMPLE_COUNT></I_TUNE_EST_C_SCALAR></RATED_CURRENT>
</ROOT>
```

How can I make this work? I currently have this code written out with my console outputs. Currently I get large numbers and not the actual inner text value for this node.

```
  public static CalibratorAverageErrorCode FindCurrentParameters(string filepath, string RatedCurrent)
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(filepath);

        int iterations = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(RatedCurrent);

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        { 
            if (node.Name == NODE_NAME)
            {
                //for each main node check if the name inner value is equal to the actual node
                //if it then gets Parametervalues and information
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Text {0}\n", node.InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine("Value {0}\n", node.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("FirchChild", node.FirstChild.Name);

                if (node.InnerText == RatedCurrent)
                {
                    iterations++;

                    foreach (XmlNode childnode in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("NAME: {0} : Data: {1} \n", childnode.Name, childnode.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if( iterations <= 0)
        {
            return CalibratorAverageErrorCode.CURRENT_NOT_FOUND;
        }

        return CalibratorAverageErrorCode.NO_ERROR;

    } //end of function
```

[image]

Comment: Can you re-post the XML?  What you've posted is invalid.  And you're using the older XML library.  System.Xml.Linq is much better. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-6.0

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: It seems that your XML sample has a repetitive **mixed content**. Please fix it.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky : XML has no issues.  My code below parse the XML without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses XML Linq and puts results into a DataTable

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement ratedCurrent = doc.Descendants("RATED_CURRENT").FirstOrDefault();
            string[] children = ratedCurrent.Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToArray();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("RATED_CURRENT", typeof(string));
            foreach(string child in children)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(child, typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add(child + "_COUNT", typeof(string));
            }

            foreach(XElement rCurrent in doc.Descendants("RATED_CURRENT"))
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                row["RATED_CURRENT"] = int.Parse(rCurrent.FirstNode.ToString());
                foreach(XElement child in rCurrent.Elements())
                {
                    string columnName = child.Name.LocalName;
                    int value = int.Parse(child.FirstNode.ToString());
                    int count = (int)child.Element("SAMPLE_COUNT");
                    row[columnName] = value;
                    row[columnName + "_COUNT"] = count;
                }
            }



        }
 
    }


}
```